# What is making the colors on this object?

Tags: objects, vertex-colors, obj

I've got a 3rd-party payware object that when imported into Blender contains colors that override the applied shader material. Where are these colors coming from? How do I make them go away?

I count at least three colors: white, gray and black, but I can't figure out why they are there. A plain white shader material has been applied to the entire object. Thanks. Blender 3.1.2, Windows 11

[image: Example]

[Blend file](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/mystery_object_colors.blend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a split normals problem (which happens with some .fbx imports), go into the *Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data*:

[image]

Comment: That works! Thank you!